# How to determine which user clicked on a button

Tags: node.js, axios, slack-api

I'm sending messages with block elements (buttons) to channel using Slack API. How can I get the username displayed when someone approves or rejects the request? I send the message using `chat.postMessage`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have [interactivity](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling) enabled for your app. Since you are using buttons you need to reference how to handle [interactive components](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#button). Essentially, you need to give your buttons an `action_id` which is it's unique identifier and will help you determine the source of the action (including the user) when the button is clicked. You will parse the action payload that sent to your app to get the user information you need and use that information in a subsequent call to chat.postMessage.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting the user with the payload, using body instead worked for me:
In Bolt Python:

```
 @app.action("approve_button")
 def approve_request(ack, say, body, payload):
     # Acknowledge action request
     ack()
     user_details = body['user']
     username = user_details['name']
     .....
```